# Angularjs: Convert JSON object to key, value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 input text and a button. User can click on add button which would create a new row having both input text as below:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ndk29mvp/3/

You can click on Add again and it would add more key value textboxes.

```
<tr ng-repeat="m in options">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="optionKey_{{$index}}" class="form-control"
               ng-model="m.optionText" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="optionValue_{{$index}}" class="form-control"
               ng-model="m.optionValue" />
    </td>           
</tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="Add()">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
```

So basically I am creating dropdowns text and value using the inputs above.

Below is my controller code:

```
$scope.options = [];

$scope.Add = function () {       
    var option = {};
    option.optionText = $scope.optionText;
    option.optionValue = $scope.optionValue;
    $scope.options.push(option);        
};
```

In my save function I want to convert the users selection of text and value and convert them into key, value pairs.
So if you run my demo above and see the console output, you would see output as:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:  {optionText: "1", optionValue: "11", $$hashKey: "005"}
1:  {optionText: "2", optionValue: "22", $$hashKey: "007"}
```

I want to remove all this optionText, optionvalue etc and just create key value pair, so that I create a json object as:

```
{ 
 "1": "11",
 "2": "22"           
}
```

So I tried the below code for doing so:

```
$scope.data = [];

_.each($scope.options, function (value) {
    $scope.data[value.optionText] = value.optionValue;
});
```

But $scope.data has the below output:

```
1: "11"
2: "22"
```

How can I correctly create my key, value format array.

Sorry if this is something trivial, but somehow I am not getting this through.
And I was not sure what to give this a appropriate heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var optionsArr = [
   {optionText: "1", optionValue: "11", $$hashKey: "005"},
   {optionText: "2", optionValue: "22", $$hashKey: "007"}
];

var obj = optionsArr.reduce( (acc,i) => {
    acc[i.optionText]=i.optionValue;
    return acc;
}, {} );

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: thanks that works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output of `$scope.options` like below.
   `{ 
         "1": "11",
         "2": "22"

    }`

Then you can modify your controller like following.

```
     $scope.options = {};
     $scope.Add = function () {      
     var option = {}; 
 $scope.options[$scope.optionText]=$scope.optionValue;
       // $scope.options.push(option);        
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code, If you expect to create the key, value pair format array

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.myOptions = []
  var optionsArr = [
     {optionText: "1", optionValue: "11", $$hashKey: "005"},
    {optionText: "2", optionValue: "22", $$hashKey: "007"}
  ];
    
  for(let value of optionsArr) {
      var option = {};
      if(value.optionText && value.optionValue) {
        option[value.optionText] = value.optionValue;        
        $scope.myOptions.push(option)
      }
  }    
  
  console.log($scope.myOptions);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```